# Problem with returning arguments that are const references

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I know why the following does not work correclty, so I am not asking why. But I am feeling bad about it is that it seems to me that it is a very big programming hindrance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string ss("hello");

const string& fun(const string& s) {
        return s;
}

int main(){
        const string& s = fun("hello");
        cout<<s<<endl;
        cout<<fun("hello")<<endl;
}
```

The first cout will not work. the second cout will.

My concern is the following:

> Is it not possible to imagine a situation where a method implementor wants to return an argument that is a const reference and is unavoidable?
>   I think it is perfectly possible.
>   What would you do in C++ in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest retitling the question. This really has nothing to do with const references; it is about the lifetimes of temporaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a slight weakness of C++. There's an unfortunate combination of two factors:

- The function's return is only valid as long as its argument is.
- Implicit conversion means that the function's argument is *not* the object it may appear to be.

I have no sympathy for people who fail to think about the lifetime of objects they have pointers/references to. But the implicit conversion, which certainly is a language feature with subtle pros and cons, is not making the analysis very easy here. Sometimes implicit conversion is bad news, which why the `explicit` keyword exists. But the problem isn't that conversion to `string` is bad in general, it's just bad for this function, used in this incorrect way.

The author of the function can in effect disable implicit conversion, by defining an overload:

```
const char *fun(const char *s) { return s; }
```

That change alone means the code which previously was bad, works. So I think it's a good idea in this case to do that. Of course it doesn't help if someone defines a type which the author of `fun` has never heard of, and which has an `operator std::string()`. Also, `fun` is not a realistic function, and for more useful routines you might not want to provide an equivalent which operates on `char*`. In that case, `void fun(const char *);` at least forces the caller to explicitly cast to string, which might help them use the function correctly.

Alternatively, the caller could note that he's providing a `char*`, and getting back a reference to a `string`. That appears to me to be a free lunch, so alarm bells should be ringing where this string came from, and how long it's going to last.

Comment: _Of course it doesn't help if someone defines a type which the author of fun has never heard of, and which has an `operator std::string()`_, but `template <typeaname T> T fun(T&& t) {return t;}` should help.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, it is important to establish the lifetimes of objects. One common technique is to decide upon an "owner" for each object. The owner is responsible for ensuring that the object exists as long as it is needed, and deleting it when not needed.

Often, the owner is another object that holds the owned object in an instance variable.  The other typical ways to deal with this are to make it a global, a static member of a class, a local variable, or use a reference-counted pointer.

In your example, there is no clear ownership of the string object. It is not owned by the main() function, because it is not a local variable, and there is no other owner.

Answer (score 3):

The technique is valid and is used all the time. However in your first example you are converting a `const char*` to a *temporary* `std::string` and attempting to return it, which is not the same as returning a const-reference to an object stored elsewhere. In the second example you are doing the same thing, but you are using the result before the temporary is destroyed, which in this case is legal but dangerous (see your first case.)

Update: Allow me to clarify my answer some. I'm saying the problem lies in the creation of the temporary and not correctly handling the lifetimes of the objects being created. The technique is a good one, but it (along with many other good techniques) requires the pre- and post-conditions of the functions be met. Part of this burden falls on the function programmer (who should document it) and partly on the client as well.

Comment: "I know why the following does not work correclty, so I am not asking why."

Comment: We know why it is broken.  He made it quite clear that this was not the issue he was asking about.

Comment: AraK: No, the temporary is not destroyed until the end of the *full expression* which creates it.  The second example does not have any problems.

Comment: @AraK: Not so. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837092/c-destruction-of-temporary-object-in-an-expression

Comment: @Roger & fbereto: I stand corrected, I checked the standards and yes you are correct: Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

Answer (score 3):

I feel your pain.  I've found other situations where returning a const reference seemed the right thing to do, but had other ugly issues.

Luckily, the subtle gotcha is solved in c++0x.  Always return by value.  The new move constructors will make things a fast as you could wish.

Comment: That is interesting, i settled to never return references to avoid this pitfall (in fact its a very dangerous pitfall I learned the hard way...). Usually I return a pointer in such cases (which gives me at least a warning to think twice about what happens behind the curtain, this helped me...).

But _how_ does c++0x enforce avoidance of this pitfall? Or does it just solve the problem by extending the lifetime of the reference in this case?

Comment: see http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/09/your-next-assignment/ and earlier articles on r-value references to see why

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree that there are situations where this is a relevant problem.

I would use a reference-counted pointer to "solve" it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it not possible to imagine a situation where a method implementor wants to return an argument that is a const reference and is unavoidable?

Wrong question to ask, really.  All you have to do is include whether the returned reference might be to a parameter (passed by reference), and **document that as part of the interface**.  (This is often obvious already, too.)  Let the caller decide what to do, including making the temporary into an explicit object and then passing that.

It is common and *required* to document the lifetimes of returned pointers and references, such as for std::string::data.

> What would you do in C++ in this situation?

Often you can pass and return **by value instead**.  This is commonly done with things like std::copy (for the destination iterator in this case).

Comment: So you agree that it is a defect in C++. You need to a documentation to fix a problem that the language cannot fix.

Comment: No, I do not agree.  Writing all code without documentation or comments is not a characteristic of my ideal programming language.

Comment: I do not see this as a defect in C++ any more than dereferencing a null pointer is a defect in C or shooting oneself in the foot a defect in a gun.

Comment: Of course some guns make it easier than others to shoot yourself in the foot. The ones with additional concealed barrels pointing downwards are best avoided by those not willing to memorise the instruction manual.

Answer (score 0):

In the upcoming C++ standard, r-value references can be used to keep your temporary objects 'alive' and would fix the issue that you're having.

You may want to look up perfect forwarding and move constructors as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for trouble in C++98 :)

This can be solved in two ways. First, you could use a shared pointer. In this case, the memory would be managed automatically by the `shared_ptr`, and you are done! But, this is a bad solution in most cases. Because you are really not *sharing* the memory between many references. `auto_ptr` is the true solution for this problem, if you consider using the heap all the time. `auto_ptr` needs one little **crucial** improvement that is not there in C++98 to be really usable, that is : Move Semantic!

A better solution is to allow ownership to be moved between references, by using r-value references, which is there in C++0x. So, your piece of code would look like(not sure if the syntax is correct):

```
string fun(const string& s) {
        return s; // return a copy of s
}
....
string s = fun("Hello"); // the actual heap memory is transfered to s.
                         // the temporary is destroyed, but as we said
                        // it is empty, because 's' now owns the actual data!
```

Comment: auto\_ptr already has move semantics, that's the whole point of auto\_ptr\_ref.  It is just awkward in C++98, and instead of changing auto\_ptr, a new name was added for the next standard.  However, I don't see the sense of throwing a completely separate object lifetime category (dynamic allocation) into the mix instead of solving the real problem.