# Unexpected result when storing c_str() of temporary std::string in a variable

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, stdstring, temporary-objects

I have a member function defined as below:

```cpp
std::string returnStringMethod()
{
    return /* some string */;
}
```

The caller looks like this:

```cpp
const char * ptr = returnStringMethod().c_str();
```

This is returning some truncated string which I did not expect. However, the following works fine:

```cpp
std::string str = returnStringMethod();
const char * ptr = str.c_str();
```

What is happening here?

Comment: "We build code once a week" => Probably off-topic, but why ? Is there anything preventing you from compiling... whenever it makes sense ?

Comment: Nah, what I was trying to say was that this and passed all tests when I last worked on this code before closing the changes.

Comment: Don't copy the pointer returned by `c_str()` unless you really know what you are doing, instead just use it directly within C-API calls. The `c_str()` method is intended to work as an adapter, that's also the reason for its *strange* name.

Comment: Good point wolf. @Pavan: Dereferencing a dangling pointer is undefined behaviour. So if you are lucky it would break, if you unlucky, it may work without a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const char * ptr = returnStringMethod().c_str();
```

In above line a temp string is returned by the function which soon goes out of scope. (and destructor is called and memory is freed)

In later version you make a local copy of string and thus the behaviour is defined.

You can also use the following

```
const std::string &str = returnStringMethod();
const char * ptr = str.c_str();
```

Using const reference would lengthen the life of temporary variable until the reference is in scope and there would be no (explicit) unwanted copies.

Comment: can you tell me when the string retunred by the function goes out of scope please?.

Comment: Immediately after the [line end](http://ideone.com/OFCjJt). But if you [keep a reference](http://ideone.com/Fpqxte), pointer is safe to use.

Answer (score 9):

The first is undefined behavior, the temporary `returnStringMethod()` is valid only until the trailing `;`, so the internal string (returned by `c_str()`) is destroyed, so you're left with a dangling pointer.

The second version is valid because `str` will be destroyed when its scope ends, and its scope is the same as `ptr` (at least in your example).

For example, the following would also be wrong:

```
const char * ptr = NULL;
{
    std::string str = returnStringMethod();
    ptr = str.c_str();
}
```

After `}`, `ptr` is no longer valid.

Comment: Can you tell me when exactly does the temporary returnStringMethod() gets destroyed in returnStringMethod().c_str()?.

Comment: @Pavan it's undefined behavior, you're essentially saying "make this an discard it instantly" in this case.

Comment: @Pavan: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837092/c-destruction-of-temporary-object-in-an-expression) for definitions. A good rule of thumb is that a temporary is destroyed immediately after the statement, which created it, has been executed. The temporary no longer exists when the following statement is executed.

Answer (score 3):

The *return value* of `returnStringMethod` is a temporary string, the lifetime of which is bound to the expression itself; this means that the `std::string` on which you call `c_str` will be destructed right after `ptr` has been initialized in `const char * ptr = returnStringMethod ().c_str ()`.

The implications of this is that the value which `ptr` has been initialized with points to memory which is no longer accessible.

---

In the latter case, where you assign the returned value of `returnStringMethod` to `std::string str` you will have a copy which lifetime is bound to the current scope. Assigning the value of `str.c_str ()` to `ptr` is therefor valid for as long as `str` is alive.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a (temporary) copy and that's where you execute the c_str().

When the temporary goes away, the char * returned by the c_str() becomes invalid.